Process names that begin with "-"
I am using a piece of software that includes a scripting language that has builtins that allow me to call system functions, for example I may write the script:
system("whoami")

and the script will run that command. I am using these builtins to run an adjacent, long-running piece of software.
when i do so, in top, ps and htop, a process appears with a command like this:
-sh -c [executable] [arguments]

In this context, why is sh prefaced with "-"?
I suppose another question would be why calling system() spawns /bin/sh at all, but to my understanding that is more of an implementation detail?

At least in C, system() always uses a shell, but not a login shell... What piece of software are you using?

I unfortunately cannot share what the software is, because of NDAs, but the question this is a duplicate of is right, and the behaviour of spawned processes (particularly their env) is consistent with this.
